# How do I find the contact point of two spheres which touch at a single point?

Tags: geometry, 3d, spheres

I have two spheres in three-dimensional space that touch at a single point, one of them controlled by a parameter $t$. I want to find the coordinates of that contact-point in terms of $t$.

The first is centered on the point $(0, 0, 1)$ with a radius of $1$, so it is represented by the equation $x^2 + y^2 + (z - 1)^2 = 1$.

The second is centered on the point $\left(t, \frac{\sqrt{2} - 1}{\sqrt{3}} t^2 - \frac{\sqrt{2} + 1}{4 \sqrt{3}}, 1 - \sqrt{\frac{3}{8}} + \frac{\sqrt{2} - 1}{\sqrt{6}} t^2 - \frac{\sqrt{2} + 1}{4 \sqrt{6}}\right)$ with a radius of $\frac{\sqrt{2} - 2}{2} \left(t^2 - \frac{1}{4}\right)$, where $-\frac{1}{2} < t < \frac{1}{2}$, so it is represented by the equation $(x - t)^2 + \left(y - \frac{\sqrt{2} - 1}{\sqrt{3}} t^2 + \frac{\sqrt{2} + 1}{4 \sqrt{3}}\right)^2 + \left(z - 1 + \sqrt{\frac{3}{8}} - \frac{\sqrt{2} - 1}{\sqrt{6}} t^2 + \frac{\sqrt{2} + 1}{4 \sqrt{6}}\right)^2 = \left(\frac{\sqrt{2} - 2}{2} \left(t^2 - \frac{1}{4}\right)\right)^2$.

For all valid values of $t$, the second sphere is located entirely inside the first except for a single point that is exactly on the surface of the first. I do also know that the contact-point lies on the line that passes through the center-points of both spheres.

I've tried using the techniques I would use to find the contact-point of two circles in a 2D plane, but they don't seem to translate into a 3D space.

Comment: $$P=O+{O'-O\over OO'}$$

Comment: @Intelligentipauca Can you elaborate? I don't understand the equation you presented.

Comment: $O'$ and $O$ are the centers of the two spheres.

Comment: @Intelligentipauca I tried it with both ways of assigning $O$ and $O'$ between the two spheres, and neither works. Am I missing something?

Comment: You should explain why it doesn't work. Anyway $O'$ is the center of the small sphere, and $OO'=1-r$, where $r$ is the radius of the small sphere.

Comment: $$
\cases{
O_1 = (0,0,1)\\
r_1 = 1\\
O_2(t) = \left(t, \frac{\sqrt{2} - 1}{\sqrt{3}} t^2 - \frac{\sqrt{2} + 1}{4 \sqrt{3}}, 1 - \sqrt{\frac{3}{8}} + \frac{\sqrt{2} - 1}{\sqrt{6}} t^2 - \frac{\sqrt{2} + 1}{4 \sqrt{6}}\right)\\
r_2(t) = \frac{\sqrt{2} - 2}{2} \left(t^2 - \frac{1}{4}\right)\\
}
$$

then we have

$$
\|O_1-O_2(t)\| = 1 - r_2(t)
$$

or

$$
\|O_1\|^2-2O_1\cdot O_2(t)+\|O_2(t)\|^2=1-2r_2(t)+r_2^2(t)
$$

Comment: @Intelligentipauca I see the issue now. I interpreted two variables placed next to each other with no operation sign between them to mean multiplication of the two variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on comments from @Intelligentipauca and @Cesareo, I figured out that the equation for the contact-point is $P = \frac{r_2 × C_1 - C_2}{r_2 - 1}$, where $C_1$ is the center of the first sphere, $C_2$ is the center of the second sphere, and $r_2$ is the radius of the second sphere.